# LaTeX cuts my line in the middle. Why?

Tags: paragraphs, sections-paragraphs

I am writing my CV in LaTeX and I dont know why but the following code cuts my first paragraph in the middle. It should be simple to know why but I have been looking for the last hours and I didn't find anything. Can anyone help me? sorry in advance if my question is to obvious :(

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, oneside, final]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[left=4.7cm, right=0.85cm, top=0.65cm, bottom=0.70cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage{scrpage2}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{marvosym}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage[francais]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,mathrsfs}
\usepackage{scrextend}
\usepackage{marvosym}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{blue}{RGB}{0,25,80}

% Title format
\titleformat{\section}{\large\scshape\raggedright}{}{0em}{} [{\color{blue}\titlerule[0.8pt]}]
\titlespacing*{\section}
{0pt}{3.8ex plus 0ex minus 0ex}{2ex plus 0ex}

% Left margin
\reversemarginpar
\marginparwidth 96pt

% DOCUMENT
% ---------------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{document}

% Command label item
\renewcommand{\labelitemi}{\raise .5ex\hbox{\tiny$\bullet$}}
\newcommand{\mymarginnote}[1]{\leavevmode
\marginpar{\normalsize\textcolor{black}{#1}}%
\ignorespaces}

\setlength\parindent{0pt}
\setlength{\parskip}{0pt plus 0pt minus 0pt}

% Personal informations and picture
\setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}%
\setlength{\fboxrule}{0.7pt}%
\begin{wrapfigure}{r}{00mm}
    \hfill
    \fbox{\includegraphics[scale=0.125]{cv_picture.jpg}}
\end{wrapfigure} 

\mymarginnote{\smash{\fontsize{13.5}{30}\textbf{Branch Warren}}}
\mbox{}

\mymarginnote{alabama 17 \\ 1870 bessemer \\ usa \\   +4179 277320  \\ bbbranch} 
Born on the 4th of March  1700

Single

US nationality

Military duties completed

branch@gmail.com

% Objective
\section{Objective}
I am looking for a full-time position at stack overflow where my skills will add value to my employer's business. 
\end{document}
```

Comment: (1) your MWE is not complete. Where is defined `\faphone` and `\faskype`? With use example-image instead your and erasing undefined symbols, moved all definition from document content to preamble, the obtained result is not damaged as you describe.

Comment: You are right, I removed them since it has nothing to do with my question. Sorry about that...

Comment: @Zarko: thanks for your great reshape :) I appreciate your suggestions

Answer (score 1):

With small changes in your code (which aren't essential):

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, oneside, final]{scrartcl}
    \usepackage[left=4.7cm, right=0.85cm, top=0.65cm, bottom=0.70cm]{geometry}
    \usepackage{soul}
    \usepackage{scrpage2}
    \usepackage{titlesec}
    \usepackage{tabularx}
    \usepackage{marvosym}
    \usepackage[francais]{babel}
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage{enumitem}
    \usepackage{wrapfig}
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,mathrsfs}
    \usepackage{scrextend}

    \usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{blue}{RGB}{0,25,80}


% Title format
\titleformat{\section}{\large\scshape\raggedright}{}{0em}{} [{\color{blue}\titlerule[0.8pt]}]
\titlespacing*{\section}
{0pt}{3.8ex plus 0ex minus 0ex}{2ex plus 0ex}

% Left margin
\reversemarginpar
\marginparwidth 96pt

% Command label item
\renewcommand{\labelitemi}{\raise .5ex\hbox{\tiny$\bullet$}}
\newcommand{\mymarginnote}[1]{\leavevmode
\marginpar{\normalsize\textcolor{black}{#1}}%
\ignorespaces}

\setlength\parindent{0pt}
\setlength{\parskip}{0pt plus 0pt minus 0pt}

% DOCUMENT
% ---------------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}

% Personal informations and picture
\setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}%
\setlength{\fboxrule}{0.7pt}%
\begin{wrapfigure}{r}{00mm}
    \fbox{\includegraphics[width=33mm]{example-image}}
\end{wrapfigure}

\mymarginnote{\smash{\fontsize{13.5}{30}\textbf{Branch Warren}}}

\mymarginnote{alabama 17 \\ 1870 bessemer \\ usa \\ 
              \,  +4179 277320  \\ 
              \, bbbranch}
Born on the 4th of March  1700

Single

US nationality

Military duties completed

\Letter \, branch@gmail.com

% Objective
\section{Objective}
I am looking for a full-time position at stack overflow where my skills will add value to my employer's business. 
\end{document}
```

I obtain:

[image]

The changes in above code in comparison to your MWE are: (i) deleted all packages loaded twice (ii) all `\newcommand` definition are moved to preamble, (iii) `pagestyle{...}` is moved from preamble to document content, immediately after `\begin{document`, (iv) image size is determined by `width= 33mm`.

I suspect, that you probably have problems with image size. Instead scale rather determine its width or even better its height.

Comment: thanks you are right it has to do with wrap figure. But however I have to redue my picture a lot (I see almost nothing at the end) in order to have the text displayed correctly. Do you have another idea?

Comment: As you see in answer, the images can be 33m  (or even more)  wide. For test purpose put frame around image: `\framebox{\includegraphics[..]{...}}` and see if there is some white space between frame and image. If it is present, than you need to trim the picture. Or put your picture somewhere, that I can download it and see, If I can managed your problem.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion but it does not seem to work, anything else in mind?

Comment: @branchwarren, this discussion is based on my guessing, so doesn't lead to solution. Now I see, that your picture is already in `\fbox{...}` . If your picture exactly fir in it, than I don't know what is wrong.  I can only conclede, that your document very differ from my above MWE.

Comment: I found the problem: is that you have the space for the caption. Therefore you have to remove it in the wrapfigure[0mm]

Comment: @branchwarren, sorry , I do not understand. In code is no caption. However, I change organization of your MWE, remove all surpluses (see answer). If this eliminate your problem, I didn't investigate. Since it works, just use it :-)

Answer (score 1):

You're using the wrong tools, in my opinion.

The header can be a single box, in which some other boxes can be placed “by hand”, for instance with `tabular`.

The `3.7cm` length will leave the left part at 1cm from the margin of the paper.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, oneside, final]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[left=4.7cm, right=0.85cm, top=0.65cm, bottom=0.70cm]{geometry}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[francais]{babel}

\usepackage{scrpage2}
\usepackage{scrextend}

\usepackage{titlesec} % not really compatible with scrartcl

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\definecolor{blue}{RGB}{0,25,80}

% Title format
\titleformat{\section}{\large\scshape\raggedright}{}{0em}{} [{\color{blue}\titlerule[0.8pt]}]
\titlespacing*{\section}{0pt}{3.8ex plus 0ex minus 0ex}{2ex plus 0ex}

% Command label item
\renewcommand{\labelitemi}{\raise .5ex\hbox{\tiny$\bullet$}}

\setlength\parindent{0pt}
\setlength{\parskip}{0pt plus 0pt minus 0pt}
\pagestyle{empty}

\setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}%
\setlength{\fboxrule}{0.7pt}%

% DOCUMENT
% ---------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{document}

\noindent\makebox[\textwidth]{%
  \hspace{-3.7cm}%
  \begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}l@{}}
  \multicolumn{2}{@{}l@{}}{\fontsize{13.5}{0}\textbf{Branch Warren}}\\[1ex]
  \parbox[t]{3.7cm}{
    alabama 17 \\
    1870 bessemer \\
    usa \\
    +4179 277320 \\
    bbbranch
  } &
  \begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l@{}}
  Born on the 4th of March  1700 \\
  Single \\
  US nationality \\
  Military duties completed \\
  \texttt{branch@gmail.com}
  \end{tabular}
  \end{tabular}%
  \hfill
  \begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}
  \fbox{\includegraphics[width=4cm,height=3cm]{example-image}}
  \end{tabular}%
}

% Objective
\section{Objective}

I am looking for a full-time position at stack overflow where 
my skills will add value to my employer's business.

\end{document}
```

I removed all the unnecessary package. I left `babel`, although it seems funny: I guess you'll be writing the CV in French.

[image]